# can't create csv a file under folder csvfile due to folder permission

Tags: php, mysql, linux, oop, zend-framework

My folder structure like this (LINUX environment and file permission are all folder 0775)

```
application
library
public
csvfile
test
log
```

My virtual host for this project:

```
ServerName example.project.local
DocumentRoot /var/www/project/public
```

For project requirement purpose i need to create csv under folder csvfile and as i mentioned my DocumentRoot /var/www/project/public.

my problem i can't create a file under folder csvfile due to folder permission(0775). if used (0777) then its okay but i need to create under(0775) permission.

i have used following code:

```
echo $output;
$filename = str_replace('public', 'csvfile', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])."/$user_time.csv";
$fp = fopen($filename, 'w');
fwrite($fp, $output);
$contenttype = "application/force-download";
header("Content-Type: " . $contenttype);
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($filename) . "\";");
```

please help to overcome this problem.

Comment: why you want 775? just set o+w permission

Answer (score 0):

Try This
ABSPATH is absolute path

```
fopen(ABSPATH.'RankCSVFILE/KeywordRankReport'.$user_time.'.csv', 'w');
```

Comment: Virtual host path: /var/www/project/public
getcwd(); /var/www/project/public
<code>
$path = str_replace('public', 'csvfile', getcwd());
///var/www/project/csvfile
// csvfile folder permission (0775)

   chmod($path,0777);
    
   $fp = fopen($path.'/'.$user_time.'.csv', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $output);
</code>
but problem is same I can’t create file due to permission reason.